# jquery create new div with using array value as id

Tags: jquery, arrays, html

hi am trying to create a new div but using the value from an array for its id

```
var divID = 'borough_'+BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex];
jQuery('<div/>', {  
    id: divID  
}).appendTo('#results');
```

doesn't seem to work ? any ideas?
UPDATE:
removed comma from the line `id: divID`,
`<div></div>` is now created but no id property is created.

From what ive tried so far the following from joes answer works:
$('#results').append('');

ie a div is created : `<div id="borough_2"></div>`

i am performing an ajax call after creating this div and wish to do:

```
success: function(data){
    // data retrived ok
    var myData = data;
    $("boroughId=" + BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]).html(myData)
}
```

using joes method the div is created but i still cant reference it to append the data recived from the ajax request. is there some scope problem perhaps?

Comment: Remove the comma after `divID`. It will break most versions of IE.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.4+ - as that signature type for the jQuery object was not added till v1.4.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" entail?  Do you get an error message?  Are only specific browsers affected, or are all of them?  Can we see some markup to go with the JS (are you certain the #results element exists)?  Do you have this inline, or in an external file?  In either case, are do you have it in wrapped in $() so that it's bound to the document load / ready event?  More info please.

Comment: no errors it doesent seem to be added to the dom, removing the comma breaks more things,
@orbling:  nice to know that it wont work in earlier versions of jquery, i am using 1.4 though

Comment: i removed the wrong comma! it does add the div but just `<div></div>` no id is added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('#results').append('<div id="borough_'+ BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex] +'"></div>');
```

If you want to keep a reference to the ID, not a problem, just do

```
var divId = 'borough_'+ BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex];
$('#results').append('<div id="'+ divId +'"></div>');
```

You can then access the new element like so:

```
$('#'+divId).doSomething();
```

Comment: thanks joe, what if i wanted to add extra params such as rel etc, would be nice to know how to use the short hand {properties: here} though

Comment: This shorthand method makes use of the browser's innerHTML method so there are no real advantages to it over the inline method. You could just as easily modify my example above to include a rel attribute as well as id.

Comment: @Dizzy: You were using the shorthand method correctly. There's some other issue if it wasn't working. And it doesn't use `innerHTML`. It uses `document.createElement`, then calls `attr` for the properties. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L123-124

Comment: @patrick: thanks at least i'm on the right lines, its strange that it works in joes example, but not if i use parameters, i'd prefer to use params and use a var for the `'borough_'+BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]'` so i can use it easily later in the script. i did try using it as `id: 'borough_'+BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]` but the result is the same. so i guess the problem is using the dynamic name

Comment: @Dizzy: Getting the name from the Array shouldn't matter, but you could try wrapping it in parentheses to see if it helps. `id:('borough_'+BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex])` I agree that the props argument is much nicer.

Comment: @patrick: had tried using paranthesis earlier and didnt make a difference, i did updayte the question, it seems to be a problem the reference to the array value, with joes method it adds the correct div and id, but i cant reference it to put the data from my ajax call, at least nothing gets put in it, the results from th ajax call is ok

Comment: @joe: sorry ive removed the answer as solved temporarily, your answer does work but, not via the method i would like.

Comment: @Dizzy Brian High np man I didn't realise that it was critical for you to keep a reference to the ID, my answer has been updated to help you out. Still doesn't use the shorthand properties but it should do what you need.

Comment: @joe: genius, solves my problem, thanks, i need to be more detailed in what i'm trying to do when i make my questions!!

Comment: @Dizzy: I see you're in an AJAX call. By any chance does it have the `data:` property set as well?

Comment: @patrick: yeah it does the data i'm sending is: 
data: "boroughId=" + BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex] + "&catIds=" + CatTagger.myIdArray

Comment: @Dizzy: Change the name of the parameter in the `success:` callback from `data` to something else like `dat` for example. There are issues in some browsers when having the `data:` property to the call set while using `data` as the name of the parameter.

Comment: @patrick: i read about that, ive got it set up to immediatley copy it to a var called myData: (so its best to pass straight as myData and not bother with the var?)
`success: function(data){
    var myData = data;
    $('#'+divId).html(myData)
}`

Comment: @Dizzy: Yes, I'd skip the `var` unless it is being used to hold a modified version of the response. Either way, I'd avoid using `data` as the parameter name for the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the div object it returns reference to itself.

var newDiv = jQuery('', {id: divID}).appendTo('#results');